# How can remove the file upload script from this php without disturbing the INSERT

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code, and it works with the File upload in it, but not without it. In other words I have to upload images in this script in order for the script to complete.

I have tried taking out the `if` section for it, but it just returns a blank page.

Here is the code...

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);

require 'scripts/php/db_connect.php';

$password = $_POST['password_entry'];

$hashPass = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
    function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "")
    {
        global $link;

        if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
            $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
        }

        $theValue = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $theValue);

        switch ($theType) {
            case "text":
                $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
                break;
            case "long":
            case "int":
                $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
                break;
            case "double":
                $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
                break;
            case "date":
                $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
                break;
            case "defined":
                $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
                break;
        }
        return $theValue;
    }
}



$username_entry = $_POST['username_entry'];

if (empty($_POST['username_entry'])) {
    die('Username must be given');
}

$user_image_dir = "user_images";


mkdir($user_image_dir."/".$username_entry, 0777, true);


if (isset($_FILES['upload']) === true) {
    $files = $_FILES['upload']; 

    for($x = 0; $x < count($files['name']); $x++) { 
        $name = $files['name'][$x]; 
        $tmp_name = $files['tmp_name'][$x]; 

        move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$user_image_dir/{$username_entry}/{$name}"); 

        //echo '<pre>', print_r($files['name'][0], true), '</pre>'; 

        $image_upload1 = ($files['name'][0]); 
        $image_upload2 = ($files['name'][1]); 
        $image_upload3 = ($files['name'][2]); 
        $image_upload4 = ($files['name'][3]); 
        $image_upload5 = ($files['name'][4]); 

    }


    $insert_upload1 = "$user_image_dir/$username_entry/$image_upload1"; 
    $insert_upload2 = "$user_image_dir/$username_entry/$image_upload2"; 
    $insert_upload3 = "$user_image_dir/$username_entry/$image_upload3"; 
    $insert_upload4 = "$user_image_dir/$username_entry/$image_upload4"; 
    $insert_upload5 = "$user_image_dir/$username_entry/$image_upload5"; 



    $editFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; 

    $editFormAction .= "?" . htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']); 





//----------------------------------------------------//

      //--// DEFINING THE TABLE VARIABLE ACCORDING TO BUSINESS TYPE AND BUSINESS SPECIFICS//--//

//----------------------------------------------------//


//CATCHING THE MAIN VARIABLE

$business_type = $_POST['business_type'];


//DEFINING THE $business_specific VARIABLE 

// if ($business_type == "Service"){$business_specifics = $_POST['business_specific_service'];} // TYPE OF TRADESPERSON

// if ($business_type == "Service"){$business_specifics = $_POST['business_specific_hairbeauty'];} // TYPE OF SALON

// if ($business_type == "Restaurant"){$business_specifics = $_POST['business_specific_restaurant'];} // TYPE OF FOOD



// FOOD AND DRINK TABLE VARIABLES

if ($business_type == "Restaurant"); {$table_name  = "food_and_drink";}

if ($business_type == "Pub"); {$table_name  = "food_and_drink";}

if ($business_type == "Take Away"); {$table_name  = "food_and_drink";}

// HOTELS AND B&B TABLE VARIABLES

if ($business_type == "Hotel"); {$table_name  = "somewhere_to_stay";}

if ($business_type == "B&B"); {$table_name  = "somewhere_to_stay";}

// SERVICES VARIABLES

if ($business_type == "Service"); {$table_name  = "services";}

if ($business_type == "Hair & Beauty"); {$table_name  = "services";}

if ($business_type == "taxi service"); {$table_name  = "services";}

// ATTRACTIONS VARIABLES

if ($business_type == "Attraction"); {$table_name  = "attractions";}

// EVENTS VARIABLES

if ($business_type == "Event"); {$table_name  = "events";}

// CHARITY VARIABLES

if ($business_type == "Charity"); {$table_name  = "charities";}

// SHOPS VARIABLES

if ($business_type == "Shop"); {$table_name  = "shopping";}


// INSERT QUERY

 $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO di_ssenisub (timestamp,
         username,
         password) 

         VALUES (NOW(), %s, %s)",

        GetSQLValueString($_POST['username_entry'], "text"), 
        GetSQLValueString($hashPass, "text"));

        if (mysqli_query($link, $insertSQL)) {
            echo "New record created successfully $username_entry";

        } else {
            echo "Error: " . $insertSQL . "<br>" . mysqli_error($link);
        }

        mysqli_close($link);


    }
```

How do i remove the File upload section without disturning the rest...

Comment: Remove that move_uploaded_file() calling line and used variables initialization codes. What is the problem. now.

Comment: what do u mean by variables initialization codes?

Comment: Egs: $tmp_name is used in that statement, so remove the following line as well.
 $tmp_name = $files['tmp_name'][$x];

Comment: insert statement is inside `if (isset($_FILES['upload']) === true)` so just removing `move_uploaded_file()` won't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In youre code insert statement is inside `if (isset($_FILES['upload']) === true)`, so you need to change it to `if (!empty($_POST))` for example (as simple validation, then you can remove all about fileuploading inside )

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);

require 'scripts/php/db_connect.php';

$password = $_POST['password_entry'];

$hashPass = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
    function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "")
    {
        global $link;

        if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
            $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
        }

        $theValue = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $theValue);

        switch ($theType) {
            case "text":
                $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
                break;
            case "long":
            case "int":
                $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
                break;
            case "double":
                $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
                break;
            case "date":
                $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
                break;
            case "defined":
                $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
                break;
        }
        return $theValue;
    }
}



$username_entry = $_POST['username_entry'];

if (empty($_POST['username_entry'])) {
    die('Username must be given');
}



if (!empty($_POST)) {




    $editFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; 

    $editFormAction .= "?" . htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']); 





//----------------------------------------------------//

      //--// DEFINING THE TABLE VARIABLE ACCORDING TO BUSINESS TYPE AND BUSINESS SPECIFICS//--//

//----------------------------------------------------//


//CATCHING THE MAIN VARIABLE

$business_type = $_POST['business_type'];


//DEFINING THE $business_specific VARIABLE 

// if ($business_type == "Service"){$business_specifics = $_POST['business_specific_service'];} // TYPE OF TRADESPERSON

// if ($business_type == "Service"){$business_specifics = $_POST['business_specific_hairbeauty'];} // TYPE OF SALON

// if ($business_type == "Restaurant"){$business_specifics = $_POST['business_specific_restaurant'];} // TYPE OF FOOD



// FOOD AND DRINK TABLE VARIABLES

if ($business_type == "Restaurant"); {$table_name  = "food_and_drink";}

if ($business_type == "Pub"); {$table_name  = "food_and_drink";}

if ($business_type == "Take Away"); {$table_name  = "food_and_drink";}

// HOTELS AND B&B TABLE VARIABLES

if ($business_type == "Hotel"); {$table_name  = "somewhere_to_stay";}

if ($business_type == "B&B"); {$table_name  = "somewhere_to_stay";}

// SERVICES VARIABLES

if ($business_type == "Service"); {$table_name  = "services";}

if ($business_type == "Hair & Beauty"); {$table_name  = "services";}

if ($business_type == "taxi service"); {$table_name  = "services";}

// ATTRACTIONS VARIABLES

if ($business_type == "Attraction"); {$table_name  = "attractions";}

// EVENTS VARIABLES

if ($business_type == "Event"); {$table_name  = "events";}

// CHARITY VARIABLES

if ($business_type == "Charity"); {$table_name  = "charities";}

// SHOPS VARIABLES

if ($business_type == "Shop"); {$table_name  = "shopping";}


// INSERT QUERY

 $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO di_ssenisub (timestamp,
         username,
         password) 

         VALUES (NOW(), %s, %s)",

        GetSQLValueString($_POST['username_entry'], "text"), 
        GetSQLValueString($hashPass, "text"));

        if (mysqli_query($link, $insertSQL)) {
            echo "New record created successfully $username_entry";

        } else {
            echo "Error: " . $insertSQL . "<br>" . mysqli_error($link);
        }

        mysqli_close($link);


    }
```

Comment: Thank you. I see the problem now :)

Comment: oh yea - forgot, you can also remove 2 lines before `if` - `$user_image_dir = "user_images";


mkdir($user_image_dir."/".$username_entry, 0777, true);`

Comment: @Nemutaisama: code-only answers tend to hide what you've changed, and so readers other than the OP may not follow what you have done. Would you consider adding an introductory paragraph as a matter of course, so your answer can be understood by more people? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

just remove the following line:
and Im not sure where the if ends

```
$user_image_dir = "user_images";


mkdir($user_image_dir."/".$username_entry, 0777, true);


if (isset($_FILES['upload']) === true) {
    $files = $_FILES['upload']; 

    for($x = 0; $x < count($files['name']); $x++) { 
        $name = $files['name'][$x]; 
        $tmp_name = $files['tmp_name'][$x]; 

        move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$user_image_dir/{$username_entry}/{$name}"); 

        //echo '<pre>', print_r($files['name'][0], true), '</pre>'; 

        $image_upload1 = ($files['name'][0]); 
        $image_upload2 = ($files['name'][1]); 
        $image_upload3 = ($files['name'][2]); 
        $image_upload4 = ($files['name'][3]); 
        $image_upload5 = ($files['name'][4]); 

    }


    $insert_upload1 = "$user_image_dir/$username_entry/$image_upload1"; 
    $insert_upload2 = "$user_image_dir/$username_entry/$image_upload2"; 
    $insert_upload3 = "$user_image_dir/$username_entry/$image_upload3"; 
    $insert_upload4 = "$user_image_dir/$username_entry/$image_upload4"; 
    $insert_upload5 = "$user_image_dir/$username_entry/$image_upload5";
```

and remove the last "}" at the end